# How to use the Processing core library with Maven?

Tags: maven, dependencies, processing, maven-central

I want to use Processing libs in my Maven project, but I can't find any artifact for dependency. Where can I get it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### *Edit*

Since Processing 3, the [official artifacts](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.processing/core) are released to maven central.

Use like this (latest version as of February 2019):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.processing</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.7</version>
</dependency>
```

---

### For old releases

You can use the stable processing libraries from [clojars.org/quil/processing-core](https://clojars.org/quil/processing-core.).

To use Clojars repository in a Maven project, add the following to your project's `pom.xml`:

#### Repository

```xml
<repositories>
    <!-- ... -->
    <repository>
        <id>clojars.org</id>
        <url>http://clojars.org/repo</url>
    </repository>
    <!-- ... -->
</repositories>
```

#### Dependency

```xml
<dependencies>
    <!-- ... -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>quil</groupId>
        <artifactId>processing-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- ... -->
</dependencies>
```

Comment: This repo is maintained by a team which develops quil, clojure framework. Hava a look [link](http://quil.info/). So, it is semi-official but no less trusted.

Comment: Since Processing 3, there is official repo on maven central: [link](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22processing-complete%22).  This is probably the right place to include dependencies from.

Answer (score 5):

***This answer is out deprecated*** since Processing version 3 (first relleased on 26 July 2014).

---

No, there isn't a repository that I could find which has up-to-date processing jars (and there isn't a repo maintained by the processing developers).

You could install the processing jars manually in your local repo (or nexus proxy if you have one)

Have a look at http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html