# Processing > Libraries > SVG Export On IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, processing

I am trying to save svg out of Processing on IntelliJ IDEA. However, when I do this, IntelliJ keeps telling me `The processing.svg.PGraphicsSVG renderer is not in the class path.``

Here is my environment.

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-191.6183.87, built on March 27, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b39 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Processing 3.5.3
Windows 10 10.0
```

What I have tried:

Step 1. Run this code in Processing IDE.

```
import processing.svg.*;
void setup () {

  size(900, 600, SVG, "E:\\test.svg");
  smooth();
}

void draw() {
  background(200);
  line(0, 0, width/2, height/2);
  System.out.print("Saved" +"\n");
  exit();
}
```

It works.

Step 2. Run above code with little modification in IntelliJ IDEA

```
import processing.core.PApplet;
~~import processing.svg.*;~~

public class Main extends PApplet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PApplet.main("Main", args);
    }

    public void settings() {
        String path = "E:\\";
        size(900, 600, SVG, path + "test.svg");
        smooth();
    }

    public void setup() {
    }


    public void draw() {
        background(200);
        line(0, 0, width/2, height/2);
        System.out.print("Saved" +"\n");
        exit();
    }
}
```

With all of necessary libs in place, run above code, IntelliJ IDEA tells me
`The processing.svg.PGraphicsSVG renderer is not in the class path.`

It does not allow me to add `import processing.svg.*;` by saying `can not resolve symbol svg`

I know the issue is related with this line `import processing.svg.*;` since IntelliJ keeps telling me it `can not resolve symbol svg` thus, I am unable to solve this.

Any help would be a life saver, thank you in advance.

Comment: It is definitely related to ”With all of necessary libs in place”. Can you give more details about how have done it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't resolve the svg symbol because it is not part of `core.jar`.

You must add all *.jars* located in your processing installation in this directory `\modes\java\libraries\svg\library` to the classpath of your IntelliJ project to enable SVG functionality.